# Conditioning on vector in Expectation

Tags: conditional-expectation

If

$$ \mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} $$

and

$$ \mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} $$

Then what does

$$ E(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x}) = E \left( \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} \bigg| \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} \right)$$

look like, is it

\begin{equation}\tag{1} E \left( \begin{bmatrix} y_1 | x_1 \\ y_2 | x_2 \end{bmatrix}\right) \end{equation}

or

\begin{equation}\tag{2} E \left( \begin{bmatrix} y_1 | x_1, x_2 \\ y_2 | x_1, x_2 \end{bmatrix}\right) \end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x})$, without expanding it out, is a common way of writing it.

And then perhaps $E \left( \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} \bigg| \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} \right)$ would be the next most common way, but not very common at all.

Comment: yes, but I am interested in what is the conditioning in the top and bottom elements.  is it either on only the element that lines up to it, or is it both elements in the conditioning, ie eqn (1) or eqn (2)?

Comment: The conditioning is on the combination of both elements, as with equation 2.